# Не получается создать переменную типа FileInfo

Tags: c#

Выдает ошибку 'FileInfo' doesn't contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments. В чем может быть проблема ?

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Tasks
{
  public class InfoAboutFile
  {
    public static void GetFullPath(string arg)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(arg);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Наведите на `FileInfo` и скажите, он точно у вас из `System.IO`? Если прописать `System.IO.FileInfo`, ошибка пропадет?

Comment: Спасибо, когда добавил System.IO.FileInfo, ошибка пропала